# Atom editor: Selecting whitespace only before/ after text

Tags: atom-editor

In the Atom editor, I want to use the keyboard command “command + shift + right arrow”, starting at the beginning of a line, to select whitespace such as a tab that precedes text. Or to go to the beginning of a blank line and select only that line. But the behavior is that the whitespace AND the text up to the some stop character (like a space, parens, quotes…) are selected.

Is there a way to change that behavior to select only whitespace and not the text that follows, to be consistent with other text editors?